# Concat date and time of string type to one TIMESTAMP column [Impala]

Tags: sql, impala

I am trying to concat two columns, which are date and time, respectively, to create one TIMESTAMP column. The time column is in weird format(`0000 is 00:00:00, 0130 is 01:30:00, 2330 is 23:30:00`), and I don't have control over the way it is stored in the system. The Impala queries are:

```
SELECT to_timestamp(concat('16-02-2014', ' 0430'), 'dd-MM-yyyy %H%M');
SELECT to_timestamp(concat('16-02-2014', ' 1430'), 'dd-MM-yyyy %H%M');
```

The result of the first query has to be `2014-02-16 04:30:00`, and the other needs to be `2014-02-16 14:30:00`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working, The right query is:

```
SELECT to_timestamp(concat('16-02-2014', ' 0130'), 'dd-MM-yyyy HHmm');
```